# LASSO number of coefs reduces with features increase

Tags: lasso

There seems to be a reverse correlation to the number of coefs I end up with, to the number of features.

I.e. as I add features, I end up with less non-zero coefficients. Seem counter-intuitive to me. Why might that be?

Comment: It seems unlikely to be a general rule, but may occur in a particular example

Comment: I think that's a really interesting question. Is there any chance you can share your experiments with us, or if the data are sensitive, create a simulation exhibiting the same behavior?

Comment: I am unable to share the data. I have 5K+ features and I have to reduce by selection/filtering to less than 1K before I get good (outside of nested_cv) test results, which is usually accompanied by more coefs being positive.

Comment: If you can come up with a simulation that produces the same results, this would be a significant step towards understanding in and of itself, and would make it much easier for us to help you. If not, maybe someone here has happened to have experience something like this before and has ideas as to what might be happening at a high level.

Comment: But at an intuitive level, what may be happening is that as we have more variables, it becomes possible to explain the phenomenon well with only a few of them (because we cover more possible dynamics; i.e. like maybe one of the new variables behaves a), but if we only have a few variables, we need many of them to even come close. In the limit, as we add infinitely many distinct variables for a fixed sample size, eventually one of them will just coincide exactly with the response and we can get away with using that single variable.

Comment: Yes, I could see that. The problem is that with more features, I get less coefs, and they may work better in nested_cv as you suggest, but on real test data they are generally poor. So adding features does not a better model make...

Comment: Firstly, if your question has to do with generalization, you should add this to the body of your question, which does not mention nested_cv or test error at all. Secondly, think about the example I gave: the x variables were generated randomly until one just happened to explain the train data very well. How well would we expect such a model to predict?

Comment: Poorly - of course. However I worry my filtering is introducing bias. Even though my test is better - it bothers me.

Comment: You'd have to tell us also about how you're filtering, and by editing the body of your question, please.

Comment: An important factor for the intuition is that including additional features adds noise that interferes with everything else.